# How to adjust grid in Django's fieldset.html

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-templates, django-views

This is a follow-up to a question I asked about modifying Django's admin forms:

I've just created a model in Django and want to use the admin form to enter information for it. The problem I'm having is that my field names are so long that they overlap the edit boxes where their values are to be entered.

If one follows the tutorial in the Django website, it's as if the label "Question:" overlapped the edit box where one was supposed to enter a question.

The relevant code seems to be in /admin/includes/fieldset.html. I've edited down to:

```
<fieldset class="module aligned {{ fieldset.classes }}">
    {% if fieldset.name %}<h2>{{ fieldset.name }} - Foo Test</h2>{% endif %}
    {% for line in fieldset %}
        <div class="form-row{% for field in line %}{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">
              {% for field in line %}
                <div>
                   {{ field.label_tag }}{{ field.field }}
                </div>
              {% endfor %} 
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</fieldset>
```

What I can't figure out how to do is to force it to give more room to  {{field.label_tag}} and to move {{field.field}} over to the right.

If it is at all helpful, here is the relevant (I believe) html that was generated:

```
<div class="form-row field-numInvestments">             
   <div>
     <label for="id_numInvestments" class="required">NumInvestments:</label><input id="id_numInvestments" type="text" class="vIntegerField" value="8000" name="numInvestments" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Any comments would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Surely it's not the HTML that is defining the width, it's the CSS.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to edit the HTML. There is no need for overriding fieldset.html or other admin templates.

What you want to do is:

- Make sure you can select your label with a css selector;
- Add a CSS stylesheet.

You can select your label by using the following css:

```
/* attribute selector selecting only the label with for="id_numInvestments" */    
label[for="id_numInvestments"] { width: 300px; }
```

or

```
/* Applies to all labels in fieldset with class='field-numInvestments' */
.field-numInvestments label { width: 300px; }
```

Make a new css file somewhere in your static directory (/path/to/my.css). 
The contents of this style sheet should be one of the css selectors above.

To include this stylesheet to the headers of the admin 'add' and 'change' pages add a 'class Media' to your ModelAdmin:

admin.py

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('/path/to/my.css',)
        }
admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Note: 'all' is for all media types. You can also use 'screen', 'print', 'projection', etc.

Done!

As an alternative Django provides a way to add css classes to fieldsets via admin.py.

The default admin stylesheet contains 'wide' and 'extrapretty' css classes. They give your admin 'add' and 'change' pages a wide and extrapretty look. This look has wider labels! So if you're lucky setting these is enough and you don't need to add a custom style sheet! :)

To set a css class for a fieldset you need to define fieldsets in your ModelAdmin.

admin.py:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
   fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide', 'extrapretty'),
            'fields': ('numInvestments', '...' ) # And all other fields.
        }),

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

If 'wide', 'extrapretty' is not sufficient, use 'fieldsets' to add a custom css class ('extra_wide') to your fieldset.

admin.py:

```
   class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        ...
       fieldsets = (
            (None, {
                'classes': ('extra_wide', ),
                'fields': ('numInvestments', 'other_field_with_wide_label' )
            }),

            (None, {
                'fields': ('other_field', '...' ) # All other fields.
            }),
        )
        class Media:
            css = {
                'all': ('/path/to/my.css',)
            }

    admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

my.css:

```
.extra_wide label { width: 300px; }
```

The advantage of fieldsets is that you can use django's default css or create the style sheet only once. The rest is controlled form admin.py. So this is better for multiple occurrences of wide labels.

Yet another alternative: Just avoid the problem.

1) Make your label shorter and use 'help_text' to explain what your field is about:

models.py:

```
numInvestments = models.IntegerField('Your total number of investments')
```

will be:

```
numInvestments = models.IntegerField('Investments', 
    help_text="Your total number of investments.")
```

2) Just make your label shorter and use fieldsets to put a title above the field that explains what this field is about:

models.py:

```
numInvestments = models.IntegerField('Number')
```

admin.py:

```
   class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        ...
       fieldsets = (
            ('Investments', {
                'fields': ('numInvestments', )
            }),
        )
    admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

I would use the css atrribute selector if I really need a long label and it is a unique exception. But if there are more long labels, I whould use the fieldset with 'wide' and 'extrapretty' or custom class ('extra_wide'). But most of the time I would try to avoid this problem by using shorter labels, help_text and grouping fields in fieldsets with titles.

Did this answer your question? I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you cannot do it from code. All you have to do is add some CSS to your labels. Something like that would do the trick:

```
fieldset .form-row label {
    width: <YourWidthHere>px;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, this is probably going to reveal how nooby I am, but which file should I place this in? I've been slashing my way through loads of Django files. I'm going to try some grepping for .form-row and see what I can make happen, but have a feeling I'm likely to miss the right file.  Anyway, thanks for the suggestion. Hopefully, I'll be able to figure out where to put it. (Or if you know, please feel free to post here - I might not find it.... thx again...)

Comment: I would create a new css file and then link to it at the top of your custom fieldset.html.  I think there is block for including extra header elements or something like that.